# Dynamically set the option values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 different lists: EmployeeNames and Names
I read the values in Names and that of EmployeeNames.

If EmployeeNames exists in Names, I must not add that value to "ToSelectBox" but to "FromSelectBox".

If EmployeeNames doesn`t exist in Names, I must add that value to "ToSelectBox" but not to "FromSelectBox".

How can I do that dynamically?

I have 2 option values as follows:

```
<select id="fromSelectBox" multiple="multiple" > 

  <% foreach (var item in Model.EmployeeNames) { %> 
           <option value="<%=Html.Encode(Item.Text)%>"><%=Html.Encode(item.Text)%></option>  
        <%}  
    %> 
    </select>
```

---

```
select id="ToSelectBox" multiple="multiple" > 

  <% foreach (var item in Model.Names) { %> 
           <option value="<%=Html.Encode(Item.Text)%>"><%=Html.Encode(item.Text)%></option>  
        <%}  
    %> 
    </select>
```

Comment: I think instead of trying to filter the lists in the view, your model should reflect the needs of the view -- return the lists pre-filtered from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to examine the data, and programmably control that.  You can do that in the controller, where you can use Linq to check for the existence of a name in one list, and follow your business rules there, then pass the final lists to a model to pass to the view.

You could put that logic in your view, but that defeats the purpose of the controller and the separation of layers.